# is it considered bad practice to write c code in objective-c / cocoa framework?

Tags: objective-c

I am writing some Objective-C code which will be publicly available. The code mainly consists of well known algorithms which would benefit from optimization. I am planning on writing most of the code in C to reduce the overhead on creating objects and garbage collection. Is this considered bad practice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No it's not. This is done quite frequently actually.

Generally one does this when one needs time critical code to run quicker (everything else equal, calling a C function is quicker than an Objective-C method).

However, it may also be nicer in some other cases to write C functions instead.

Remember though that Objective-C is a superset of C. Everything C can do, Objective-C can do, and it should not be considered bad to do anything C can do. There may be cases where doing some things is discouraged, but anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> Premature optimisation is the root of all evil

Whether it is good practice or not depends entirely upon the application.  In most cases, I would say write it in Objective-C first then use a profiler for optimisation if it is too slow.

However, there are cases where you know you'll be needing to do optimisation, for example if you are writing a language interpreter or a CPU emulation.  In those cases (and in cases where profiling shows a bottleneck) it's perfectly fine to write pure C.

Answer (score 0):

No its not, Many of Apple's own frameworks are mostly C like Core Graphics or Accelerate. C is very good for functions that you will use alot and need to run fast, like math functions.

Answer (score 0):

There are slews of cases where an OO model, especially with single dispatch, just does not make sense.  For a general function there may be no clear preferred "receiver".  A language that supports multi-dispatch generic functions would be my preference as such a language supports both what most people think of as OO and so much more as well as fully supporting just plain old C style functions.